# asp.net button disable postback but keep validation

Tags: asp.net, ajax, validation, button, autopostback

I want to make a password recovery function where the users needs to enter the mail adress.
The mail adress has to be validated by asp.net. I dont want the site to refresh after reseting password. Thats why I disabled autopostback for my button. The problem is that disabling the autopostback also stopped the validation of the input.
I dont want to use javascript to validate the input.

So is it possible to disable autopostback but keep the validation behaviour?

Thanks alot!

This is my asp.net code:

```
<asp:Label>Email: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox id="emailTextbox" TextMode="Email" runat="server" CSSClass="emailTextbox"/>
<asp:Button Text="Anfordern" runat="server" CSSClass="ResetPassword" CausesValidation="True"/>
```

and this is the called ajax behind the button

```
function ResetPassword() {
        alert($("#<%=emailTextbox.ClientID%>")[0].value);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/pages/passwordRecovery.aspx/ResetPassword",
            data: '{mail: "' + $("#<%=emailTextbox.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
               //alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "I disabled autopostback for my button" ? The ASP.NET button control does not have an AutoPostback property.

Comment: If you want to cause a partial postback - so that the page doesn't "refresh" when you post the form - but still use ASP.NET validation, you should look at using an UpdatePanel. If that isn't what you want, you could just perform validation yourself client side, and only post to the server-side handler if the input is valid.